# Как распознать неправильный глагол(в Английском) с помощью nltk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Как распознать неправильный глагол(в Английском) с помощью nltk?

Comment: А как он выглядит ?

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/howto/parse.html

Comment: А глагол может быть в любом времени? В прошедшем времени всё выглядит просто, проверяем, оканчивается ли глагол на `ed`, в противном случае мы нашли неправильный глагол.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку множество неправильных глаголов у нас счётно, то мы можем организовать словарь группы глаголов с формами. А `nltk` нам в этом случае поможет только на этапе определения части речи, выделив глаголы в предложении. К сожалению, в отличие от `spaCy/udpipe`, текущие модели `nltk` не умеют определять для слов граммемы.